# Variance of Transformed Random Vectors

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, normal-distribution

Consider an $n$-dimensional normal random vector $\mathbf X:= (X_1, \dots, X_n)^T$ with mean $\mathbf 0$ and covariance matrix $\mathbf \Sigma$. Now define a new random vector $\mathbf Y:= (a_1X_1, \dots, a_nX_n)^T$, where $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are distinct constants. What is the distribution of $\mathbf Y$, please? I vaguely remember that $\mathbf Y$ should still be a normal random vector with mean $\mathbf 0$. However, I cannot figure out its covariance matrix. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$Y=Diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)(X_1,\dots,X_n)^T$$

So $Y$ is normally distributed as a linear transform of a normally distributed vector.

Now you have the following properties for random vector $X$ and a (non-random) matrix $A$:
$$E(AX)=AE(X)$$
This implies that $E(Y)=0$.
$$V(AX)=AV(X)A^T$$
From this you can find the covariance matrix of $Y$. You can also find it "by hand" by calculating $Cov(Y_i,Y_j)$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Comment: The mean of Y is 0, right?

Comment: Yes. $E(X)=0$ so $E(Y)$ too.